# Is there a built in way to make Karate's pathMatches case insensitive?

Tags: netty, karate

I'm using Karate Netty to mock an existing service so we can more easily test our integration with custom data.  We just realized that the existing service accepts paths with non-matching cases (.../api/EndPoint is treated the same as .../api/endPoint etc)

Is there a way to use the pathMatches functionality to accept whatever cases we send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you can write helper functions and stick them in the `Background`. Something like this:

```
Background:
* def pathIs = function(x){ return karate.get('requestUri').toLowerCase() == x }

Scenario: pathIs('/foo/bar')
```

You will miss the auto-setting of variables for `/path/{params}` though. But the point is - you can use any custom code you want, even Java if needed.

Comment: I don't know if we have a standard implementation (it was before my time) but this is how we're setup:
We have a file that's being used for routing when calls are made. That file has lines like:
Scenario: pathMatches ('foo/bar')
* call read('fooBar.feature)
Scenario: pathMatches('foo/bar/two')
* call read('fooBarTwo.feature')
That file right now has about 50 different routings.  I want to avoid having to use || pathMatches('Foo/Bar') kind of logic.
Does that open up any different possibilities? Is requestUri a global variable I could use like: Scenario: pathMatches(pathIs(requestUri)?

Comment: @ScottMacDonald you are spot on. sorry my bad, typed answer in a hurry. does the edit look better ?

Comment: Yeah, that looks good.  So I can use the function inside a normal pathMatches.  Swanky.  Thanks!